# SFMC Overwrite target data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I want to use query studio activity to write a query between two tables using a join. So lets say there is table1 and table2. I want to delete the data in table2 based on all the data in table1. So if it is in table 1 I do not want it in table2. I can not overwrite the data extension cause the query includes table2. What can I do

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete rows in data extension via query, you can create a DE3, join  DE1 and DE2 then overwrite DE3.

alternatively, you can create a Boolean field to mark the record as exclusions in DE2 and update DE2 from Query, then use that field to exclude in journey entry criteria or exclusion script, but in this approach, record is not deleted from the DE2